# Increment for loop by adding counter to itself

Tags: python

In java you can increment a for loop by adding the counter to itself.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i += i)
    System.out.print(i + " ")
----
1 2 4 8 16
```

Is there a python equivalent?
The following does not work.

```
for i in range(1, 10, i+=i):
    print(i, end=' ')
----
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Another question came up during experimentation.

```
for i in range(1,10,i):
    print(i,end=' ')
print()

for i in range(1,20,i):
    print(i,end=' ')
print()

for i in range(1,30,i):
    print(i,end=' ')
print()

for i in range(1,40,i):
    print(i,end=' ')
print() 
----
1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
1 20 
1 21
```

The main question is whether there is a python equivalent. 
The other question is what is going on when the step is i.

Comment: You could use a different loop `while` for example. Part of the problem is that a range object is created immediately at `range(start, stop, step)` each value is not generated as the loop goes on

Comment: When the step is `i`, whatever value the name `i` refers to is passed to the `range` function... So taking your code at face-value, what is happening here would be a `NameError`

Comment: In your second question, the range is evaluated in advance, so whatever value `i` already has is used. In your first loop, it's already been assigned outside of the code you're showing.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure your Java for-loop should print `1 2 4 8`

Comment: Yea, I fixed the post to be `(i < 20)`. Thanks. What do you mean by NameError? Also, even if `i` is taking whatever value it was previously assigned, that doesn't explain why `range(1,20,i)` prints as if the step was `1` whereas the others are doing something entirely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a generator that does it:

```
def doubleRange(start, end):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += start

for i in doubleRange(1, 10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `for` loops are for-each loops, like Java's `for (Type thing : container)`, not like Java's `for (init; test; increment)`.

If you want an init-test-increment style loop in Python, you need to use `while`:

```
i = 1
while i < 10:
    # loop body
    i += i
```